# Perfect forwarding for wrapper classes

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding

I have for example a wrapper class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
};
```

And some proxy class that takes does something with `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Proxy {
    T t;
    void operator()() const {/* .... */}
}
```

Now there is for convenience a method that creates the proxy, and I have written overloaded it for l- and r-value reference:

```
template <typename T>
Proxy<const T &> createProxy(const Wrapper<T> &w) {return {w.t};}

template <typename T>
Proxy<T> createProxy(Wrapper<T> &&w) {return {std::move(w.t)};}
```

This of course is just the stripped down code I wanted to use, but to make everything more readable, I want to use some perfect forwarding magic that results in less code making everything a bit more readable:

```
template <typename Wrapper>
Proxy</* ??? */> createProxy(Wrapper &&w) { /* ??? */ }
```

So the question is, how can I deduct the l- or r-value type of a member of an l- or r-value type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask (and less so why you only get around to it in the last 1 to at most 3 paragraphs).

Answer (score 2):

`std::forward<Wrapper>(w).t` has the same value category as `w`, so all you need to do is return a `Proxy` with `&&` stripped from `decltype((std::forward<Wrapper>(w).t))`:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference<T&&> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using remove_rvalue_reference_t = typename remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;

template <typename Wrapper>
auto createProxy(Wrapper&& w) ->
  Proxy<remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype((std::forward<Wrapper>(w).t))>> {
    return {std::forward<Wrapper>(w).t};
}
```

**[Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5a40ab3502671be)**

Comment: `std::remove_rvalue_reference` does the same thing as the above one right?

Comment: @user1447257 If there *was* a `std::remove_rvalue_reference`, that is what it would do. There's [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference), and [`std::add_rvalue_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference), but no `remove_rvalue_reference`.

Comment: Ah yes, just saw recognized my misreading of the doc. Anyways, thank you!